# XML autocompletion according to RNG schema

Tags: javascript, xml, fsm, relaxng

Let `RNG` be a relax NG specification, `XML` be a valid XML document relative to `RNG`, designate `n` be the `n`th character of the `XML` document, `B` a node of `XML` and `XML[n = B]`  the XML document where the node `B` is inserted at the character `n`.

I want to define a function `suggest(RNG, XML, n) → {Node} = O` such that

- for any `B ∈ O`, `XML[n = B]` is a valid XML document relative to `RNG` and,
- for any `C ∉ O`, `XML[n = C]` is *not* valid.

---

For now, I have tried two approaches:

1. Using a double recursion on `XML` and `RNG`, at the element`XML[n]` containing the `n` the character and the RNG `<element>` `RNG[n]` matching `XML[n]`, and return a tuple `(boolean, suggestions)`, then decide what to return next based on those two elements. For instance, if the current `RNG` node is a choice between `A` and `B`, if `fn(A)[0]` is true and `fn(B)[0]` is false, return `(true, fn(A)[1])`, if they are both false then `(false, [])`, and if they are both true, ..., well `(true, fn(A)[1] + fn(B)[1])` might not be too bad, but certainly isn't always the right anwser.
2. Using a "state machine", with four piles (say `*r` with the children of `RNG[n]`, `*x` with the children of `XML[n]`, `*c` with the current choices that are being solved, and `*s` with the output suggestions), such that

- if `*r` equals `*x`, then pop `*r` and `*x`, if `*r` doesn't equal `*x`, then pop `*r` and push it in `*s`,
- if `*r` is a choice between `A` and `B`, then push `(*r, *x, B, null)` in `*c` and push `A` in `*r`.
- if `*r` is a ref, pop it and push the matching definition, if it is a definition process it as a group,
- if `*r` is a group, push its element to `*r`
- if `*c[0]` equals `*r`, and `*c[2]` is a node, then pop it, set `*r` and `*x` to `*c[2],*c[0]` and `*c[1]` respectively, push `(*r, *x, null, *s)` in `*c`
- if `*c[0]` equals `*r` and `*c[2]` is null, then pop it, compare `*s` and `*c[3]`, then, decide **(and that's quite hard)**, which one to keep.
- simplify the other nodes in terms of choices and groups (not so hard), such that they only have two elements.

But both have not been so successful:

1. Both a are horrifingly slow on a large schema
2. The first one fails frequently because of too much recursion, especially if the RNG contains multiple `<ref>`s, and it gets quite difficult to check for infinite loops too.
3. The second one uses an awful lot of memory, because I have to deep copy each XML nodes on every `<choice>` I encounter.
4. Writing tests is hard because of the number of possible cases, and I can't find a way to generate them programatically. So actually, I am not even sure my function produces a valid XML document.
5. It is still not clear to me how I should be handling `<choice>`s. For instance, take `<choice><element name="a" /><group><element name="a" /><element name="b" /></group></choice>`: how should I encode this so that *all* valid nodes are suggested?

---

I know that multiple editors (e.g. http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/ for Emacs) offer this option, but I am not sure they do indeed produce valid documents, and I am not familiar enough to read through Lisp.

So I am searching for a "good way" to implement this on DOM, or, even better a JavaScript library that would allow to do that.

Comment: What does `fn(A)[0] ` mean?